# Java Servlet 3.0 and @webservlet

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

Trying to access a Servlet from a button on HTML page

//Html Page

```
FORM method="GET" action="/StudentDBServlet">
```

yada yada

```
INPUT type="submit" value="Register" name="Register">
```

//My Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name="StudentDBServlet", urlPatterns={"/StudentDBServlet"})
public class StudentDBServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

The servlet is located in Package `com.zzz.studentregistration`

When I hit the "Register" Button this is the url create

```
http://localhost:8080/StudentDBServlet?FirstName
```

but it needs to be this to work properly

```
http://localhost:8080/com.zzz.studentregistration/StudentDBServlet?FirstName
```

How or where do I add the package name to the Servlet definition?
I tried adding to various parts if @WebServlet but no luck ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet container couldn't care less about your servlets' package. Only the `urlPatterns` matter. Your code above should work just fine. It is not clear what (and why) do you want to achieve. You can simply write:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/com.zzz.studentregistration/StudentDBServlet"})
```

But then the form has to point to this particular servlet:

```
<FORM method="GET" action="/com.zzz.studentregistration/StudentDBServlet">
```